# Search with a wildcard and replace on the same line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I am attempting to edit a large text file with the following general format:

```
ID=id1;Name=name1
ID=id2;Name=name2;Note= sometext2 ~X0A1D5PFF5 othertext2;
ID=id3;Name=name3;Note= sometext3 ~Q87362 othertext3;
ID=id4
ID=id5;Note= sometext5 ~G1NYZ3 othertext5;
ID=id6;Name=name6;Note= sometext6 ~M1C0K5 othertext6;
ID=id7
...
```

My goal is generate a file with the same line order, but for lines containing strings with the `~` prefix, replacing the ID on the same line with that string (whilst stripping the tilde). Line that don't include `~` strings should just be printed as is.  i.e., produce this:

```
ID=id1;Name=name1
ID=X0A1D5PFF5;Name=name2;Note= sometext2 ~X0A1D5PFF5 othertext2;
ID=Q87362;Name=name3;Note= sometext3 ~Q87362 othertext3;
ID=id4
ID=G1NYZ3;Note= sometext5 ~G1NYZ3 othertext5;
ID=M1C0K5;Name=name6;Note= sometext6 ~M1C0K5 othertext6;
ID=id7
...
```

So far I've been trying to use `sed` and `awk` but I can't seem to get the regex right...

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex groups:

```
sed -E 's/^ID=[[:alnum:]]+;(.*)~([[:alnum:]]+) /ID=\2;\1~\2 /' file > file.modified
```

- `-E` - use extended regex
- `^ID=[[:alnum:]]+` matches the existing ID
- `(.*)~` - matches everything up to the `~`
- `([[:alnum:]]+)` - matches the alpha numeric token following the `~`
- `ID=\2;\1~\2` - the replacement string that references the regex groups

Output:

```
ID=id1;Name=name1
ID=X0A1D5PFF5;Name=name2;Note= sometext2 ~X0A1D5PFF5 othertext2;
ID=Q87362;Name=name3;Note= sometext3 ~Q87362 othertext3;
ID=id4
ID=G1NYZ3;Note= sometext5 ~G1NYZ3 othertext5;
ID=M1C0K5;Name=name6;Note= sometext6 ~M1C0K5 othertext6;
ID=id7
```

Comment: This is close, but it appears that the existing ID value is not being replaced... rather the new ID is just prepended. i.e., 
   `ID=id2;Name=name2;Note= sometext2 ~X0A1D5PFF5 othertext2;` becomes:    `ID=X0A1D5PFF5;ID=id2;Name=name2;Note= sometext2 ~X0A1D5PFF5 othertext2;`

Comment: You are right - I realized the issue and updated the answer.  Please check.

Comment: It still doesn't appear to work... in the edited form, there is no substitution.

Comment: I got the results as seen in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{if(match($0,/~[^ ]*/)) sub(/id[0-9]/,substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1))}1' file
```

Brief explanation,

- `match($0,/~[^ ]*/)`: search the pattern which matched regex `/~[^ ]*/`
- `substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH)`: return the sub-string append the tide character
- `sub(/id[0-9]/, substr)`: replace the first substring matching the regex